# Is it possible to access the run_status object when using Chef.event_handler?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a bit of a catch-22 that I can't seem to find a solution for.  I can successfully do this:

```
#
# Cookbook:: core_unix_base_cmcb
# Recipe:: email_on_fail

email_hash = node.default['core_unix_base_cmcb']['email_hash']
email_hash['mailserver'] = node['postfix']['main']['relayhost']
email_hash['subject'] = "Subject: Chef-client run failed on #{email_hash['hostname']}"
email_hash['message'] = "A Chef-client run failed on #{email_hash['hostname']}."
email_hash['recipient'] = [ 'someone@somewhere.com' ]

Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_failed do
    SendEmail::Helper.new.send_email(email_hash)
  end
end
```

```
require 'net/smtp'

module SendEmail
  class Helper
    def send_email(email_hash)
      msg = "From: #{email_hash[:sender]} < #{email_hash[:sender]}@#{email_hash[:hostname]}\n"
      msg << "To: #{email_hash[:recipient].join('; ')}\n"
      msg << "#{email_hash[:subject]}\n"
      msg << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
      msg << "#{email_hash[:message]}\n"
      sender = 'chef-client-noreply@somewhere.com'
      Net::SMTP.start(email_hash[:mailserver], 25) do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message msg, sender, email_hash[:recipient]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However - I need the message to include the chef-client run_status.
If you add

```
msg << "#{run_status.formatted_exception}\n"
msg << Array(backtrace).join('\n')
```

to the above example, The run_status isn't defined.

The only examples I've been able to find are with custom handlers using the report interface, and the chef_handler resource declaration.  So I tried this (from an example I found):

```
chef_handler 'SendEmailOnFail::SendEmail' do # Full class name
  # relative path to your handler
  source ::File.expand_path('../../files/default/handlers/email_on_fail_helper.rb', __FILE__)
  # source 'email_on_fail_helper.rb'
  arguments email_hash  # Hash or Array to pass to handler constructor
end
```

```
require 'net/smtp'

module SendEmailOnFail
  class SendEmail < Chef::Handler
    def report(email_hash)
      if run_status.failed?
        msg = "From: #{email_hash[:sender]} < #{email_hash[:sender]}@#{email_hash[:hostname]}\n"
        msg << "To: #{email_hash[:recipient].join('; ')}\n"
        msg << "#{email_hash[:subject]}\n"
        msg << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
        msg << "#{email_hash[:message]}\n"
        msg << "#{run_status.formatted_exception}\n"
        msg << Array(backtrace).join('\n')
        sender = 'chef-client-noreply@somewhere.com'
        Net::SMTP.start(email_hash[:mailserver], 25) do |smtp|
          smtp.send_message msg, sender, email_hash[:recipient]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When you do a chef-client run with that code, it errors out on the arguments (received 1, expected 0).
I found absolutely no examples online where def report had any parameters, so I am presuming that is the issue.  The parameters are required for our organization because the mail server isn't always the same, and the recipients aren't always the same.

So how can I get the information of what failed in a chef-client run in the body of the E-mail message, AND have parameters passed to the library (or custom handler)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for the replies.  After continuing to scour the internet after posting my question, I finally ran across a nugget I could use.
https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/7101

I got lucky with this example:

```
on :run_failed do |exception, run_status|
```

I don't really understand how that works, or where it's documented, but it's essentially the same thing as what you are doing, seshadri_c, and works well.  I can access the things I need to compose a message, such as

```
run_status.run_context.cookbook_collection
```

Comment: I wish these options were documented. I found the `do |exception|` example [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/docs/dev/design_documents/event_handler_recipe_dsl.md). I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `run_status` is available only with `report` interface as described in the [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_handler/#handler-custom-object-run-status).

> The `run_status` object is initialized by Chef Infra Client before the `report` interface is run for any handler.

**However...**

> *So how can I get the information of what failed in a chef-client run in the body of the E-mail message, AND have parameters passed to the library (or custom handler)?*

*It is possible* to get exception details from `run_failed` block of `event_handler`. Some of the methods are: `message`, `backtrace`, `full_message`, etc.

There is a reference for having variables for `:run_failed` block [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/docs/dev/design_documents/event_handler_recipe_dsl.md).

For example, in my **recipe** I am adding `message` to my `email_hash`. This will then be passed to the helper method for sending email.

```rb
# Adding this for completeness, the required change is in "Chef.event_handler" block
email_hash = Hash.new
email_hash['node_name'] = Chef.run_context.node.name
email_hash['subject'] = "Chef run failed on #{email_hash['node_name']}"
email_hash['sender'] = 'admin@example.io'
email_hash['recipient'] = 'user@example.io'

# This is where we can access details of "exception"
Chef.event_handler do
  on :run_failed do |exception|
    email_hash['error_msg'] = exception.message
    SendEmail::Helper.new.send_email(email_hash)
  end
end
```

Adding my `SendEmail` helper **library** for completeness again:

```rb
require 'net/smtp'

module SendEmail
  class Helper

    def send_email(email_hash)
      message = "From: #{email_hash['sender']}\n"
      message << "To: #{email_hash['recipient']}\n"
      message << "Subject: #{email_hash['subject']}\n"
      message << "Date: #{Time.now.rfc2822}\n\n"
      message << "Chef run failed on #{email_hash['node_name']}\n"
      message << "#{email_hash['error_msg']}\n"
      Net::SMTP.start('localhost', 25) do |smtp|
        smtp.send_message message, email_hash['sender'], email_hash['recipient']
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to set the email_hash as an attribute, report handler can access the node object with the node method o you could do `run_status.node['email_hash'][xxx]` instead of `email_hash[xxx]`.

Doc around the run_status object in handlers is [here](https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_handler/#handler-custom-object-run-status)

For a more detailed exchange, feel free to join Chef's slack for community help (and there's Chef's devs there too which help a lot for inner bits): https://community-slack.chef.io/